# Код на python работает только в режиме отладки

Tags: python, qt, visual-studio-code, pyside6

Код скомпилированный в .exe не запускается на 2 из 6 компьютеров.
Также кроме режима отладки код запускается из стандартной idle python.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QByteArray
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QAudioFormat
from PySide6.QtCore import QByteArray, QIODevice,QByteArray
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import (
    QAudioDevice,
    QAudioFormat,
    QAudioSource,
    QMediaDevices,
)
import wave
class Microphone():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.m_devices = QMediaDevices()
        self.m_pullMode = False
        self.io:QIODevice
        self.initialize_audio(QMediaDevices.defaultAudioInput())
    def initialize_audio(self, device_info: QAudioDevice):
        format = QAudioFormat()
        format.setSampleRate(8000)
        format.setChannelCount(1)
        format.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat.Int16)

        self.m_audio_input = QAudioSource(device_info, format)
        self.io = self.m_audio_input.start()
wf = wave.open("output.wav", 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(QAudioFormat.Int16)
wf.setframerate(8000)
micro=Microphone()
while (micro.io.isReadable()):
    len = micro.m_audio_input.bytesAvailable()
    buffer_size = 2048
    if len > buffer_size:
        len = buffer_size
    buffer:QByteArray
    buffer = micro.io.read(len)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(buffer))
wf.close()
```

Comment: Ну так может быть просто `micro.io.isReadable()` на этих 2х компьютерах возвращает `False` и программа выходит из цикла.

Comment: И что же происходит в режиме отладки?

Comment: ```micro.io.isReadable()``` возвращает None, из-за того что ```QAudioSource``` не создается, а вот почему он не создается не понятно.

Comment: Работает как и задумывалось в режиме отладки, то есть идет запись с микрофона.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что `start` работает асинхронно. По крайней мере [в примере в документации](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qaudiosource.html#details) производится подписка на события. Из документации не очень понятно, но судя по примеру, я бы читал данные после того, как состояние `QAudioSource` перейдет в ActiveState. В отладке может работает потому, что у вас из-за отладчика и точек останова искусственная задержка. На каких-то компах может успевать стартовать устройство. Так же в обработчике состояния полезно проверять не случилась ли ошибка (это есть в примере).

Comment: Добавил проверку, выдает ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'``` я так понимаю ```QAudioSource``` не создается, так как раньше выдает это ```QAudioSource: failed to open audio device```.

Comment: Note: This Python example is not fully complete as compared to its C++ counterpart.
Only the push mode works at the moment. For the pull mode to work, the class
QIODevice have python bindings that needs to be fixed.

Возможно еще не полностью доделали привязку qt?